# Solving and plotting an SIR epidemiology model

Tags: differential-equations

Folks, please advise me about solving and plotting an SIR epidemiology model.

The model is given by:

```
Sus'[t] = (-a) Sus[t] Inf[t] ,

Inf'[t] = a Sus[t] Inf[t] - b Inf[t] ,

Recov'[t] = b Inf[t],

Sus[0] = 'some number' , Inf[0] = 'some number', Recov[0] = 'some number' , 

a = 'some number', b = 'some number'
```

I did not find any help on-line and the explanation in the lecture is far from clear for me.

I tried to adapt the code from [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/132305/trying-to-do-an-sir-model), but failed and was asked to use the former one.

Comment: This demonstration should answer this question: ["SIR Epidemic Dynamics"](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/SIREpidemicDynamics/).

Comment: @AntonAntonov, thanks, but it does not. I checked it before. I am not looking for theoretical aspects, but for a chunk of code to plot it. This is the problem of this tool - not enough resources to educate myself.

Comment: **1.** "I am not looking for theoretical aspects, but for a chunk of code to plot it. " -- Please, examine that demonstration again -- the code is in the demonstration. **2.** "This is the problem of this tool - not enough resources to educate myself." -- What tool are you talking about?

Comment: Dear @AntonAntonov, I sincerely apologize for my ignorance, but I do not quite understand where is it in the "demonstration"? I do not see it. Would you be so kind to be more specific please. I am very new to Mathematica. And I find it much less abundant with code examples than R, which I usually use.

Comment: "I am very new to Mathematica. And I find it much less abundant with code examples than R, which I usually use." -- Mathematica is much better documented than R -- since R is often somewhat inadequate people have written and posted on the web a lot about how to deal with R's inadequacies. (If you curious about how and why that happens find and read the article "The Lisp Curse".)

Comment: "I do not quite understand where is it in the 'demonstration'?" -- Two ways to get the code. 1) Download the demonstration notebook and in that notebook press the button "Download source code". 2) In the demonstration's web page page press the button "Source".

Comment: Dear @AntonAntonov, thanks a lot for such clarification! As I stated before, I am new to this language and did not have any idea how to export code. I cannot use your code, because it will be a violation of academic integrity at my school (and I remind everybody to keep this in mind!) but it might give me ideas how to adapt the given code. Many thanks again. I will read a suggested reading too.

Comment: Good luck with your studies! (And my code is pretty straightforward application following the documentation.)

Comment: @AntonAntonov, thanks, I will be here frequently. I still did not figure out it myself with my code :). But I appreciate your clarification, it will help me in the future! All the best!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I more or less copied and pasted into `NDSolve` the formulation given in the original post and replaced "=" with "==".

```
ClearAll[Sus, Inf, Recov, a, b, tmax]

tmax = 20;

soln = First@NDSolve[{
    Sus'[t] == (-a)*Sus[t]*Inf[t],
    Inf'[t] == a*Sus[t]*Inf[t] - b*Inf[t],
    Recov'[t] == b*Inf[t],
    Sus[0] == 762,
    Inf[0] == 1,
    Recov[0] == 0, a == 0.00218, b == 0.44036}, {Sus, Inf, Recov}, {t,0, tmax}]

Plot[{Sus[t] /. soln, Inf[t] /. soln, Recov[t] /. soln}, {t, 0, tmax},
  PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> {"Sus", "Inf", "Recov"}, 
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]