# How to model the following system of ODE's in Mathematica with plots of the solution?

Tags: differential-equations, modeling

Consider the following

**(i)**

\begin{align}
\frac{d S}{dt} &= -\frac{\beta S I}{N}\\[2ex]
\frac{dI}{dt} &= \frac{\beta S I}{N}
\end{align}

Where $N=S+I$ is the total population.

**(ii)**

\begin{align}
\frac{dS}{dt} &= \mu N -\frac{\beta S I}{N} - \nu S\\[2ex]
\frac{dI}{dt} &= \frac{\beta S I}{N} -\nu I
\end{align}

Where $N=S+I$ is the total population.

**(iii)**

\begin{align}
\frac{dS}{dt} &= -\frac{\beta S I}{N} + \gamma I\\[2ex]
\frac{dI}{dt} &= \frac{\beta S I}{N} -\gamma I
\end{align}

Where $N=S+I$ is the total population.

**(iv)**

\begin{align}
\frac{dS}{dt} &= \mu N -\frac{\beta S I}{N} +\gamma I - \nu S\\[2ex]
\frac{dI}{dt} &= \frac{\beta S I}{N} -\gamma I -\nu I
\end{align}

Where $N=S+I$ is the total population.

How can I model these in Mathematica with plots of the solution? What about further models with 3 or 4 equations in the system with more parameters?

A solution for the SIR model:

[image]

My attempt at a code:

```
ClearAll[S, P, R, b, g, tmax] 
tmax = 100; 
n[t_] := S[t] + P[t] + R[t]
soln = First@NDSolve[{  S'[t] == (-b/n[t])*S[t]*P[t], P'[t] == (b/n[t])*S[t]*P[t] - g P[t], R'[t] == g P[t], S[0] == 0.99, P[0] == 0.01, R[0] == 0, b == 0.07, g == 1}, {S, P, R}, {t, 0, tmax}] 
Plot[{S[t] /. soln, P[t] /. soln, R[t] /. soln}, {t, 0, tmax}, PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> {"S", "I", "R"}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

Comment: What is the issue? I have coded the first problem and I do get a solution

Comment: @DiSp0sablE_H3r0 I don't know how to code it, if I get an example, I should be able code the rest(in theory anyway..)

Comment: Look for [SIR model](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/208357/solving-and-plotting-an-sir-epidemiology-model)

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I tried that solution but didn't get correct answer after playing with it for a bit, since my question includes $N$ with $N=S+I+R$.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann here is my code for my SIR model: 
ClearAll[S, P, R, b, g, tmax]
    
    tmax = 100;
    
    soln = First@NDSolve[{
        n[t] == S[t] + P[t] + R[t]
           S'[t] == (-b/n)*S[t]*P[t],
        P'[t] == (b/n)*S[t]*P[t] - g*P[t],
        R'[t] == g*P[t],
        S[0] == 0.99,
        P[0] == 0.01,
        R[0] == 0,
        b == 0.07,
        g == 1},
       {S, P, R},
       {t, 0, tmax}]
    
    Plot[{S[t] /. soln, P[t] /. soln, R[t] /. soln}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
     PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> {"S", "I", "R"}, ImageSize -> Large]

Comment: @Math In your code I found parameter `n` and function `n[t]`!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I must've sent a code I was playing with ah! could you fix it because I have no success for the moment..

Comment: @Math Please post your code in your question!

Comment: I'm getting formatting errors which is why I couldn't.. I couldn't post my original question in terms of equations without getting formatting errors!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I did the editing. So now it should be in proper form

Comment: I edited  "My attempt at a code"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a numerical solution of the code you presented in the comment:

```
tmax = 10;
b = 0.07;
g = 1;
n[t_] := S[t] + P[t] + R[t]
SPR = NDSolveValue[{S'[t] == (-b/n[t])*S[t]*P[t], 
P'[t] == (b/n[t])*S[t]*P[t] - g  P[t], R'[t] == g P[t], 
S[0] == 0.90, P[0] == 0.1, R[0] == 0.}, {S, P, R}, {t, 0, tmax}] ;
Plot[{Through[SPR[t]], Total@Through[SPR[t]]} // Evaluate, {t, 0,tmax}, PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Automatic, Automatic, Dashed}]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 from me. I always like the solutions you suggest. This is not an exception. However, I do believe that the problem should be fully stated originally and not as a comment. This is not a comment about you, rather about the usefulness of the post itself

Comment: @DiSp0sablE_H3r0 Thanks, my full agreement!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Can you get something similar to this? I'll attach the image in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully, after this example, you should be able to code the rest.

I am assuming that $\beta$ is just a constant.

Then, we begin by defining `n[t_] := s[t] + i[t]` as the problem suggests.

We write down the two equations:

```
eqn1 = D[s[t], t] + beta (s[t] i[t])/n[t];
eqn2 = D[i[t], t] - beta (s[t] i[t])/n[t];
```

Now, we brute-force `DSolve` them

```
DSolve[{eqn1 == 0, eqn2 == 0}, {s[t], i[t]}, t] // Flatten
```

A sanity check: we define the functions to be given by the answer of `DSolve`

```
s[t_] := C[1] - (E^(beta t) C[1])/(E^(beta t) - E^(C[1] C[2]))
i[t_] := (E^(beta t) C[1])/(E^(beta t) - E^(C[1] C[2]))
```

and then we run the two equations. If we are correct we should get two nice zeroes

```
eqn1 // Factor
eqn2 // Factor
```

which we do.

In order to plot the solutions:

we have to assign numerical values to the undetermined constants.

```
plot1 = Plot[{s[t]} /. C[1] -> 2 /. C[2] -> 3 /. beta -> 5, {t, 0, 
   5}]
plot2 = Plot[{i[t]} /. C[1] -> 2 /. C[2] -> 3 /. beta -> 5, {t, 0, 
   5}]
plot3 = Plot[{n[t]} /. C[1] -> 2 /. C[2] -> 3 /. beta -> 5, {t, 0, 5}]
```

And you get three plots.

[image]

[image]

[image]

You can combine them

```
Show[plot1, plot2, plot3]
```

[image]

Comment: Why doesn't it let me edit the question? it says "formatting error". this happened when I asked the question which is why I had to put the equations in code format

Comment: I don't know what to tell you about that. Sorry. Did you try the above? Is this example clear?

Comment: I tried it but didn't get a plot. also could you edit this code in the question: 
 ClearAll[S, P, R, b, g, tmax]
      tmax = 100;
     soln = First@NDSolve[{
        n[t] == S[t] + P[t] + R[t]
           S'[t] == (-b/n)*S[t]*P[t],
        P'[t] == (b/n)*S[t]*P[t] - g*P[t],
        R'[t] == g*P[t],
        S[0] == 0.99,
        P[0] == 0.01,
        R[0] == 0,
        b == 0.07,
        g == 1},
       {S, P, R},
       {t, 0, tmax}]
      Plot[{S[t] /. soln, P[t] /. soln, R[t] /. soln}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
     PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> {"S", "I", "R"}, ImageSize -> Large]

Comment: Can you check again? I have shown how to plot

Comment: I don't get any plots, they're blank..?

Comment: No they are not blank. I have added the plots as well. You should Quit[], then run all the commands I wrote down and you should get the plots as well

Comment: These plots that you show do not make sense unfortunately, maybe because of $C_1$ and $C_2$. we should get this: https://docs.idmod.org/projects/emod-generic/en/latest/_images/SI_InsetChart_vitaloff.png

Comment: With all due respect, you have to realize that you have not given any initial or boundary conditions to specify anything. I obtained the solutions for the problem that YOU wrote down. Suggesting that these plots do not make sense is wrong. These are the plots of the solutions for the equations of the OP. I am not a magician to guess all the missing bits of information.

Comment: Ok, I understand. However I did mention you add my code from the comments to the question since I'm getting errors when doing so, then you would've seen the initial conditions!

Comment: I was writing the answer while you were writing the comment and I did not check afterwards.

Comment: ok no problem. as you see, I cant edit the question without getting formatting errors for some reason.. can you kindly edit the question back?